# Android : Will this be a good pattern for communication between threads in Activity and Fragments?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, message-queue

i am using *HandlerThread* class for thread communications in an Android App.

The main UI thread(Activity) has it own handler,with its *handleMessage(Message)* overriden to accept message and process it.

*HandlerThread* 's are created and they use the handler of main thread to send it messages.

Now the complexity arises when fragments come in,
the **fragments run on the UI thread(main)**, so i can't have another handler for the same main thread in fragment class.

so a solution i thought of is to,

- Send a reference of handler of main thread to fragment via the argument bundle.
- Use that reference to obtain message object and send message in threads created in fragment class.
- The activity forwards this message to the fragment via a predefined interface.
- So finally, the fragment receives the messages from the threads it started.

***would this be a good ,reasonable pattern? or a bad one? any better approach is available?***

Please share your knowledge about this.

Thank you,
Regards,
Abhijith

Comment: please first read about java concurrency, one of good books in this topic is: Java Concurrency in Practice, then yu'll probably know how to do it.

Comment: `"the fragments run on the UI thread(main), so i can't have another handler for the same main thread in fragment class."` you can have as many handlers running on the same thread as you want

Comment: @pskink Thank you, i thought multiple handlers wouldn't work, it works fine and crisp now ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are actually trying to achieve using this pattern

but suggestion is, hosting activity should be considered to manage all operations, It could be done through an interface where hosting activity will receive callbacks from fragments on certain events.